# I downloaded macOS 10.13.1 Beta 2 two times but it isn't installing

Tags: macos, mac, high-sierra

Last night, I wanted to upgrade my system, so I downloaded macOS 10.13.1 Beta 2, but after downloading 2 GB files, it didn't do anything. I waited 10 mins but it was still the same, on App Store it just says "Update".

So I downloaded it again with press Update button, and it downloaded 2 GB again. But still it is just saying "Update". It didn't restart, didn't open the installer or anything.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the updater downloads to your **Applications** folder.  There you will see an icon there that you can click on to update.

You can use **Launchpad** to see the icon, or go directly to your Applications folder.

[image: update high sierra]

Comment: I know it goes there, but it isn’t here. Even App Store doesn’t say “Downloaded”. It stil says “Update” in Updates page.

Comment: @oguzhanvarsak I see.  Then it may be useful to others who try to help you if you include that you are aware of the fact that the updater puts the installer in the Applications folder.  Honestly, based on your question I wasn't to know that, hence my answer and attempt to help.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

This happens even releases for general use due to corrupt downloads, bad file on the server, date/time/signing errors. Especially when the Mac App Store does the download instead of a web browser or other more explicit file download tool.

Since this is a beta update, I'd check within your beta channel support community to see if others are having this issue.  Not only is the code being tested, the software infrastructure to deliver the update could be beta / testing, too. This redo / uncertainty / breakage is big part (perhaps the overriding reason for existence) of participating in beta software evaluation.

Comment: Good general answer, I will edit it since betas go out several ways - not just developer beta.  Your general point is correct though - probably is just an incomplete download or code signing error that needs fixing on the sending side and OP did nothing wrong except not go to Apple for support.